# Does the sum of the Zeta function taken on natural numbers converge?

Tags: riemann-zeta

Does this series 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n\ge2} \zeta(n) 
\end{equation*}
converge? If yes is it easy to prove ?

Comment: What is $Z(n)$?  What is $Z(1)$?

Comment: I can't type the Zeta symbol, Z(s) is $\sum(1/n^s)$ Yes Z is not defined on 1 but you can take my sum from 2.

Comment: @www `\zeta` will give you the symbol $\zeta$.

Comment: You can just [ask the machine](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[Zeta[n]%2C{n%2C2%2CInfinite}]) before you ask here.

Answer (score 2):

$\zeta(n)>1$ for all $n>1$, so no.

Comment: On the other hand, $\sum_{n\ge 2} (\zeta(n) - 1)$ has a nice closed form :).

Answer (score 1):

$\zeta(n)=1+\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{3^n}\cdots>1$, so the sum of zeta diverges, in particular because of the first $1$ term. On the other hand there's a very cute modification:

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(\zeta(n)-1)=1,$$

and generalizations, I believe due to [Borwein, Bradley and Crandall](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//zeta/borwein1.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

As $Z(1)$ is infinite, the sum will be infinite as well.

Taking the sum from $n=2$, consider 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{Z(n)}{1}.
$$
We have
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{Z(n)}{1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{2^n}+\dots}{1}=1.
$$
By the limit comparison test, http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx, this means that the Zeta series converges if and only if the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1$ converges. Hence the series diverges.

Comment: I meant taking the sum from 2 I will update

Comment: @www updated the answer